# Syntax for Overloading Type Conversion Operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm sorry if this has been asked already, but I'm still learning C++ and struggling with a bit of syntax.

I'm supposed to overload the type conversion operator, so that it will accept an object and return an int value, based on a protected int inside that object.

Header file:

```
definitions.h

class Baseballs 
{
protected:
    int currentValue;
public:
    Baseballs(int);
    int operator= (Baseballs&); // ??????
}
```

Methods:

```
methods.cpp

#include "definitions.h"

Baseballs::Baseballs(int value)
    {
    currentValue = value;
    }

int Baseballs::operator=(Baseballs &obj) // ??????
    { 
        int temp = obj.currentValue;
        return temp; 
    }
```

So in main.cpp, if I create an object:

```
Baseballs order(500);
```

Then 500 is assigned to `currentValue`.  I need to be able to assign that to an int variable, and ultimately print it for verification, such as:

```
int n = order;
cout << n;
```

What I'm having trouble with is the syntax for overloading `=`.  Can someone tell me what the proper syntax for the definition and method should be?

Comment: Your assignment operator should be returning `Baeballs&` and providing the integer value either as a cast-operator or as a member function getter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overloaded `=` is really to assign to objects of the *same* type. Ex:

```
order = another_order;
```

What you are looking for is an overloaded *conversion* operator.

```
operator int() { return currentvalue; }
```

However this is generally not regarded as good practice, due to unknown conversions. An `explicit` overload is much safer:

```
explicit operator int() {...}
```

However you would need to do:

```
int n = static_cast<int>(order);
```